# exec() return nothing for specific command

Tags: php, exec, shell-exec

I want to use ipset through php to autoban ips depending on their behavior. And I managed to do it:

```
echo exec('sudo ipset version');
```

is working! `ipset v6.20.1, protocol version: 6`

```
echo exec('sudo ipset -A setname 1.2.3.4');
```

Also works, ip is firewalled. But

```
echo exec('sudo ipset test setname 1.2.3.4');
```

Is not working (it works in terminal), it prints nothing. It should print `1.2.3.4 is in set setname.` Even `shell_exec('sudo ipset list setname')` works, it prints all ips in this set. But `ipset test` is not working through php.

It makes me spend a lot of time before I tried to test it with other command. What is wrong with this command? Why it is returning nothing? It prints usual string in server terminal.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#refsect1-function.exec-returnvalues) of `exec()` :

> Return values : The last line from the result of the command. [...]

To get the full output, you have to use the `&$array` parameter :

```
exec('sudo ipset test setname 1.2.3.4', $lines) ;
$output = implode('\n', $lines) ;
```

The documentation of `shell_exec()` said :

> Execute command via shell and return the complete output as a string

**Inside PHP :**

Inside PHP, there is two functions, for different PHP functions :

From `/ext/standard/exec.c` :

- `exec()`, `system()` and `passthru()` calls internally :

  ```
  /* {{{ php_exec
   * If type==0, only last line of output is returned (exec)
   * If type==1, all lines will be printed and last lined returned (system)
   * If type==2, all lines will be saved to given array (exec with &$array)
   * If type==3, output will be printed binary, no lines will be saved or returned (passthru)
   */
  PHPAPI int php_exec(int type, char *cmd, zval *array, zval *return_value)
  ```

  Called by `PHP_FUNCTION(exec)`, `PHP_FUNCTION(system)` and `PHP_FUNCTION(passthru)`.
- `shell_exec()` calls internally :

  ```
  /* {{{ proto string shell_exec(string cmd)
     Execute command via shell and return complete output as string */
  PHP_FUNCTION(shell_exec)
  ```

This two functions are pretty the same, except that `php_exec` use `php_stream_get_line()` that store a buffer of lines, and `PHP_FUNCTION(shell_exec)` calls `_php_stream_copy_to_mem()` that stores all data in a single buffer.

Comment: `ipset test setname 1.2.3.4` returns only one line (is it included or not), and I tested it with `shell_exec()`. I think it has something to do with permissions, maybe `ipset test` reads something and I only have permission for executable. But reading whole set `ipset list setname` is working! It is very strange. Anyway, everything works great now, besides `ipset test`. So it can be ipset question, not php, I have no idea, can't google anything out.